# Getting Link Title Using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse the title of links using BeautifulSoup. I have tried various things but just can't get it to work.

The html is behind a login so here's a screenshot:

[image]

And here's my latest attempt which I was sure would work but just returns "None".

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
links = soup.find_all('ul', class_='nav list-group')
print(links)

for link in links:
    title = link.get('title')
    print(title)
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line of code:

```py
links = soup.find_all('ul', class_='nav list-group')
```

Is not extracting the links, it's extracting the `<ul>` tags. Instead, you could try extracting the links with something like:

```py
links = soup.find_all('a', class_='odds')
```

Then you will be able to loop over them and extract your titles:

```py
for link in links:
   print(link['title'])
```

Answer (score 1):

##### What happens?

You are selecting the `<ul>` not its `<a>` so you wont get any `href` value.

##### How to fix?

Select more specific e.g. with these `css selector` that will find all `<a>`  that has an `title` attribute, in your `<ul>`:

```
links = soup.select('ul.nav.list-group a[title]')
```

##### Example

**Note:** *Your question needs some improvement, so you should provide specific part of `driver.page_source` as text and not as image - Took your code, so it is just a hint.*

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

for link in soup.select('ul.nav.list-group a[title]'):
    title = link.get('title')
    print(title)
```